# Adding and removing a document listener in Angular 2 outside of the constructor

Tags: angular, listener

I have a popup component whose template is movable.  The popup opens when the `open()` method is called and the movable listeners are attached; then closes when the `close()` method is called but the listeners aren't removing.  These are on the class level:

```
@Output()
open() {
    const div = this.someDiv.nativeElement;
    div.addEventListener('mousedown', this.move.mouseDown.bind(this), false);
    div.addEventListener('touchstart', this.move.touchStart.bind(this), false);
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', this.move.mouseMove.bind(this), false);
    document.addEventListener('touchmove', this.move.touchMove.bind(this), false);
    document.addEventListener('mouseup', this.move.mouseUp.bind(this), false);
    document.addEventListener('touchEnd', this.move.touchEnd.bind(this), false);
    this.display = 'block';
}

@Output()
close() {
    const div = this.someDiv.nativeElement;
    div.removeEventListener('mousedown', this.move.mouseDown.bind(this), false);
    div.removeEventListener('touchstart', this.move.touchStart.bind(this), false);
    document.removeEventListener('mousemove', this.move.mouseMove.bind(this), false);
    document.removeEventListener('touchmove', this.move.touchMove.bind(this), false);
    document.removeEventListener('mouseup', this.move.mouseUp.bind(this), false);
    document.removeEventListener('touchEnd', this.move.touchEnd.bind(this), false);
    this.display = 'none';
}
```

It works great; however, removing the listeners isn't working even though I'm trying to reference the same function.  How do I remove the listeners in this context?

P.S. I'm sure there's a better way to register document events which would be helpful to know too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though a new re-written approach may be able to use the `@HostListener` Angular method, the problem here was in the use of the native JavaScript `.bind()` prototype method.

> The bind() method creates a new function... [Function.prototype.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

In other words, using `bind` is like using an anonymous function with the benefit of providing the `this` context—meaning that you're not referencing the original object, but the newly created function.  So, though I thought I was explicitly pointing to the same object so I could remove the listener, when using `bind` I have to create a reference to the concerned object and pre-bind it first, then point to that pre-bound reference:

```
private moveMD = this.move.mouseDown.bind(this);
private moveTS = this.move.touchStart.bind(this);
private moveMM = this.move.mouseMove.bind(this);
private moveTM = this.move.touchMove.bind(this);
private moveMU = this.move.mouseUp.bind(this);
private moveTE = this.move.touchEnd.bind(this);

@Output()
open() {
    const div = this.someDiv.nativeElement;
    div.addEventListener('mousedown', this.moveMD, false);
    div.addEventListener('touchstart', this.moveTS, false);
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', this.moveMM, false);
    document.addEventListener('touchmove', this.moveTM, false);
    document.addEventListener('mouseup', this.moveMU, false);
    document.addEventListener('touchEnd', this.moveTE, false);
    this.display = 'block';
}

@Output()
close() {
    const div = this.someDiv.nativeElement;
    div.removeEventListener('mousedown', this.moveMD, false);
    div.removeEventListener('touchstart', this.moveTS, false);
    document.removeEventListener('mousemove', this.moveMM, false);
    document.removeEventListener('touchmove', this.moveTM, false);
    document.removeEventListener('mouseup', this.moveMU, false);
    document.removeEventListener('touchEnd', this.moveTE, false);
    this.display = 'none';
}
```